# Display first line of content in WordPress without shortcodes

Tags: php, wordpress, preg-match

I am pulling in content from a wordpress post by using the following code:

```
<?php the_content(); ?>
```

When the text is output on the page it contains the shortcodes used in the content which I want to strip out but still keep the content. See below:

```
[vc_row][vc_column width="1/1"][vc_column_text]
artist name
[dt_divider style="thin"/]

image size
[dt_divider style="thin"/]

£70[/vc_column_text][dt_gap height="20"][vc_column_text]Description[/vc_column_text][/vc_column][/vc_row]
```

All I am wanting to do is keep the artist name section but when I use:

```
<?php strip_shortcodes( $content ); ?>
```

It removes the all the text as it is wrapped inside a shortcode.

Does anyone know a better way of keeping just the artist name bearing in mind the artist name will be different in each post?

Many thanks :-)

Comment: Have you try regular expressions ? You put the preg-match tag but you don't talk about :/

Comment: Not sure about regular expressions. I am still a bit of a newbie to php. Will have a read about it and get back to you. Thanks

Comment: Is the artist name always between `vc_column_text]` and `[dt_devider` ?

Comment: Yes, it is always between those.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According that the artist name always between `vc_column_text]` and `[dt_devider`.

```
preg_match_all("/\[vc_column_text\](.*)\[dt_/Us", $source, $matches);
$artist_name = $matches[1];
```

Comment: Thanks! Will have a go with it and let you know :-)

Comment: Just needed to add an extra [0] onto the `$artist_name = $matches[1][0];` but it worked a treat.